# Insert ToC after part in book class?

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec, tocloft, scrbook

So I am using the scrbook class and have a very large document - which recently got larger. From a previous question of mine, in which I had a few separate scrbook documents and wanted to combine them into a single larger one, each document became a part in this new, much larger document.

While I have fancy headers and minitocs at each chapter's start, I do not have a Part ToC after the part page. I was curious as to how I can do that?

Sub-question - how to renumber chapters to be start at 1 after each part?

I am using

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% TITLE / SECTION HANDLING
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{cuted}              %for printing minitoc without pagebreak
```

Comment: titlesec and KOMA? tocloft and KOMA?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer ?

Comment: It is a wellknown fact that titlesec and KOMA classes should not be used together.Compilation warns you about this

Comment: @ChristianHupfer if it is well known, it is not to me :) I do not get a Compilation warning with the editor that I use. Why shouldn't they be used together?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer btw I am not a TeX power user. I would say my TeX prowess is above someone who used it once or twice and would maybe hesitantly say rudimentary.

Comment: 'Off-Topic' - Comment: You have a bunch of questions, most of them have answers, but you accepted only two answers -- this is not really 'appreciating' the help provided by others to you.

Comment: Slightly on-topic: Perhaps I misunderstand what you mean by "part" in this context. But I believe that a book, divided into parts (often using separators) still has a single table of contents, before the first part.

Comment: @RobtAll by part I mean `\part{<name-of-part-here>}`. True, prior to the first part there is the main ToC. I would like to make a "mini" toc, but after each part (while also having a minitoc for each chapter)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I think I am misunderstanding something somewhere. Yes, I have a lot of questions; I am not very good at TeX. This post has a main question - how to have a ToC after each part. I searched TeX exchange prior to posting this about getting a ToC after each part (in a variety of phrases and key words). I found a lot of answers for modifying minitoc for chapters / sections as well as modifying what ToC displayed (and how many sub sections it shows). My TeX is not proficient enough to translate those answers to one of my own.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer ah, I mis-understood your 'Off-Topic' comment. Other SE sites remind you to accept answers, I just forgot. I upvote the answers I find useful or actually use to solve the problem in the end (on my questions or otherwise). Just went back and marked answers I found sufficient.